# Fallout Shelter: Benefits of having Specials over 10, in the wasteland

Tags: fallout-shelter

This question is specific to dwellers who are out exploring the wasteland. Not in production rooms.

I am aware that in the wasteland, dwellers who have Endurance over 10(by equipping an outfit which increases Endurance on top of having full(10) Endurance) will not suffer radiation damage.

My question is, do any of the other Special stats also have benefits if they are over 10? I have not noticed anything but I may very well have missed something.

Comment: If your Perception was higher you might have noticed something...